# Variable not passing to form properly

Tags: typescript, sabre

I'm trying to populate the value of textbox retentionx with 0OTHXXGK1DCA19JUN-thank you. The information in the textbox is stopping at 0OTHXXGK1DCA19JUN-thank it will not take the space and you

**Main.ts**

const retentionDate = '0OTHXXGK1DCA' + datesService.getNow().add(179,
days').format('DDMMM').toUpperCase() + '-thank you';

getService(LayerService).showInModal(new PnrView({model: {retentionx: retentionDate}}), pnrOptions , {display: 'areaView'});

**PNRView.html**

```
<label>{{_t 'Retention'}}</label>
<input type="text" id="{{new-random 'retention-field'}}"
class="not-empty form-control input-form retention-field-cl"
value={{retentionx}}>
```

Comment: Hi - which API are you trying to use? And without testing the "gui" i recall there was a char limit and some fields which do not allow for spaces

Comment: Hello - At this point I'm not using any API. I create the variable in Main.ts and then pass it to show on the PNRView.html. When the user submits it will be sent to sabre host/emulator API.

Answer (score 0):

The value requires "".

`<label>{{_t 'Retention'}}</label> <input type="text" id="{{new-random 'retention-field'}}" class="not-empty form-control input-form retention-field-cl" value="{{retentionx}}">`